# three.js: some parameters of TorusGeometry look odd in r57

Tags: three.js

Parameters of TorusGeometry are radius, tube, radialSegments, tubularSegments and arc.
It seems that radialSegments and tublarSegments are inverse in point of name and function.
For example, TorusGeometry(40, 40, 32, 3) is expected to be a shape like U.F.O, but it doesn't work so. In contrast, TorusGeometry(40, 40, 3, 32) works well.
I'm using r57 and confirmed with Firefox19 and IE9+ChromeFrame26.

If this problem is already known, ignore this post.

Comment: The parameter names could be improved. I wouldn't worry about it if I were you. Use whatever works.

Comment: I think he's right though. The parameters seem to be switched.